# Workign with floating <li> elements in footer

Tags: html, css, html-lists

My website is on the local server right now however this will be a simple fix for those of you who know whats it's called.

I'm trying to get these lists (bordered in white) to float the the far left in the available space of the footer(bordered by black).

[image]

This is my CSS

```
#footer { width: 100%; height: 503px; background: url(img/FOOTER-bg.jpg) repeat-x; background-color: #821d20; position: relative; top: 100px;/*border: 1px solid #0C0;*/}
#footer a { text-decoration: underline; color: #c7bd89; }
#footer a:hover { text-decoration: none; color: #fff; }

#footer h6 { background: url(img/FOOTER-HR-BG.jpg) left center repeat-x; text-align: left;}
#footer h6 span { background: #8e2023; display: inline-block; padding-right: 5px; }


.footer-widgets { width: 960px; height: 503px; margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; border: 1px solid #000;}
.footer-widgets li { width:280px; height: auto; list-style-image: none; list-style-position: outside; list-style-type: none; float: left; color: #fff; padding: 13px; margin-right: 10px; /*border: 1px solid #fff;*/ }
.footer-widgets li ul {color: red;}
.footer-widgets li ul li {color: #fff; margin-left: -50px; margin-top: -15px;}
.footer-widgets li p { font-size: 1em; line-height: 18px; text-align: left; /*border: 1px solid red;*/  }
.footer-widgets li h2 { font-size: 1.4em; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: 1px; line-height: 30px; text-align: left;}
.footer-archives { position: relative; top: -210px;}
.footer-widgets li.last { position: relative; top: -210px;}

h6 { font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: 1px; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #fff;}

.footer-copyright { position: absolute; width: 900px; left: 50%; margin-left: -450px; top: 400px; height: 100px; font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; line-height: 22px; font-size: 1em; color: #fff; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; }
.footer-copyright a { color: #fff !important; text-decoration: none !important; }
.footer-copyright a:hover { color: #c7bd89; text-decoration: underline !important; }

.copyright { margin-top: 27px; text-transform: uppercase; display: block; color: #cc9798;}
.copyright a { color: #cc9798 !important; text-decoration: underline; }

.footer-one, .footer-two, .footer-three, .footer-four { border: 1px solid #fff; float: left;}
```

I have the containing footer and within the 900px x 503px container I wish that all lists float left (and under each other if it's small enough). So "Archives" would flow under "Follow Us" and if I were to put a search bar under "Testimonials" it would fit.

What can I do with my CSS to have this happen?

Comment: Are you clearing your floats?

Comment: P.S. Lists are easier to manage when you style the CONTENTS of the list and not the list itself. See: http://preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists/

Comment: looks like you have the search and the map after the Testimonials in the DOM. You might haver to put them in the same column as the content you want to align it with.

Comment: Can you post the HTML and/or create a jsFiddle?

Comment: @j08691 I believe this is the right way of doing it. My first time using it myself. http://jsfiddle.net/Yp259/1/

Comment: @Diodeus: I've tried. I added overflow:auto to my ul class but it didn't do anything but add a scroll-bar of which I do not want. I don't want my text hidden either. I've also applied styles to the <li> in whole and not individually. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why no just create a column for each side (left, center, right) and simulate it that way, well atleast I think this is what you are trying to achieve

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eEwdk/

Theres another workaround that would consist in making each li element absolute positioned and calculating it's position (yeah I know it's sound redundant)

Comment: Soudns like it would be a good fix (both ways) however this content will be dynamic, so I won't know the heights ever.

Comment: There's no problem if you don't know heights, usually thats defined by it's content :) http://jsfiddle.net/eEwdk/1/ I added heights to show you the example

Comment: Looks great Will be incorporating this tonight to test it out on the site.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want each of the `li` elements underneath one another.  To do that you want to float the `ul` element to the left, not each individual `li` element.

Comment: Looking at Paradise's solution, it seems like I was misunderstanding what you wanted.  I was suggesting to *only* float the `ul`, not the `li`'s, but that would only create a column of `li`'s.  Go with Paradise's approach, should work fine :)