# CSS stacking div with variable height on two columns

Tags: html, css

So I'm working the profile page of a user on my website. And I'm having a little problem with the CSS.

My problem is the following: I have four div boxes with a fixed width but with variable heights and I would like them to stack one on top of an other.

The picture bellow is a screenshot of my issue, the div with the title "Latest videos" should be glued to the one with the "basic info" title. Like "contact info" and "Latest photo" are.

[image: My problem]

My html looks something like this :

```
<div style="margin-left:-10px">
    <div class="infoBox" style="width:360px;  margin-left:9px">
        Content goes here for basic info
    </div>
    <div class="infoBox" style="width:360px;  margin-left:9px">
        Content goes here for contact info
    </div>
    <div class="infoBox" style="width:360px;  margin-left:9px">
        Content goes here for latest photos
    </div>
    <div class="infoBox" style="width:360px;  margin-left:9px">
        Content goes here for latest videos
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS class for info box looks like this :

```
.infoBox {
    width: 100%;
    margin: -1px; 
    background-color:#37312d;
    padding:5px;
    border:#5b504a solid 1px;
    margin-bottom:9px;
    float:left;
}
```

How can I do to make this work ?

Comment: You're floating them all left, I would imagine floating two right and two left would get what you're looking for, or am I missing something?

Comment: I feel like something is off here. I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pm67/1/) in which I made the container `760px` wide, and everything lines up. Is there something more to the CSS here? Perhaps there's an issue with the content itself?

Comment: this question might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302056/workign-with-floating-li-elements-in-footer/10303004#10303004

Comment: @Eric: That's because they all have the same height; try adding extra content to them: http://jsfiddle.net/7pm67/2/ - and then if you float two of them right it looks as intended: http://jsfiddle.net/7pm67/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short of [nesting your divs in columns](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/P82js/1/):

```
<div class="left-column">
    <div class="infoBox">...</div>
    <div class="infoBox">...</div>
</div>
<div class="right-column">
    <div class="infoBox">...</div>
    <div class="infoBox">...</div>
</div>
```

you could try [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/ZMTAk/) demonstrating its use.

Comment: Great link, and I think this will more fluidly give Joris what he wants. +1

Comment: I'm going to look into this even though I would have preferred a solution that didn't include javascript. Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of CSS solutions on this page! [Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/pWvsh/) using nested divs as columns.

Comment: Yes, I know but I was kind of hopping for a dynamic css way of handling it, without the need for the nested divs.

Comment: [Check this out](http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/) and give the [third option](http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/masonry/demos/css.html) a shot. It's pure CSS (albeit CSS3,) and will work in current versions of Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the boxes in columns [like so](http://jsbin.com/orafuf/1/edit).  This is a very basic grid system, but it shows the basic idea: you're stacking your boxes inside of wrapper divs which form columns.

If you'll be repeating this pattern all over your site, you may want to use a more formalized grid system.  Many examples can be found by simply searching "css grid system".

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you divide the content into two columns:

HTML:

```
<div style="margin-left:-10px">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="infoBox" style="width:360px;  margin-left:9px">
            Content goes here for basic info
        </div>
        <div class="infoBox" style="width:360px;  margin-left:9px">
            Content goes here for latest videos
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="infoBox" style="width:360px;  margin-left:9px">
            Content goes here for contact info
        </div>
        <div class="infoBox" style="width:360px;  margin-left:9px">
            Content goes here for latest photos
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in your CSS add:

```
.column{float:left; width:50%;}
```

UPDATE: the boxes inside the columns don't need to be floated if you use this solution

Comment: The only change I would make to this would to make `column` a class and not an ID, since you mean to share that among multiple elements.

Comment: This could work, I'm gonna go try it and see it if is a practical solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have found for this issue is to tag each post with the class .odd and .even or .left and .right then simply float left the odd/left posts and float right the even/right posts. Note that this only works visually if the widths of the posts add up to the width of their container. Then to make this work on a variety of screen sizes simply add an @media query to change the float on the even/right posts to be left on screens smaller than the width of the dual column container.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
#bottom{
    width: ???px;
    height: ???px;
    background-color: black;
}
#top{
    width:???px;
    height:???px;
    background-color:red;
    z-index: 999;
}


<div id="bottom">
    <div>......</div>
  <div id="top">......</div>
</div>
```