# CSS for responsive column styled site - stacked divs with variable height

Tags: css, html, css-float

I am currently building a responsive website but am having trouble position four of the divs on the homepage. (my website is http://wealthartistry.com.au/wa. I have the same problem as the person that posted this: [CSS stacking div with variable height on two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357697/css-stacking-div-with-variable-height-on-two-columns)

However, the solution to put the stacked divs in two separate columns will not work as my website is a responsive site, and when the browser width gets to 799px, i need the divs to stack in this order (if you visit the website and drag the edge of the browser narrower you will see what i mean):

*

[Top left]

[Top right]

[Bottom left]

[Bottom right]

*

If the divs are put in columns like so:

[Column 1] [Column 2]

then the order will end up as:

[Top left]

[Bottom left]

[Top right]

[Bottom right]

*

Is there any way around this?

My basic css code is like this:

```
#contentbox1wrapper {
width: 46.25%;
float: left;
}

#contentbox1 {
padding: 50px;
background: #383838;
margin-bottom: 75px;
}

/*height of div is determined by the amount of content inside*/

#contentbox2wrapper {
width: 46.25%;
float: right;
}

#contentbox2 {
padding: 50px;
margin-bottom: 75px;
background: #1e75bc;
}

#contentbox3wrapper {
width: 46.25%;
float: left;
clear: left;
}

#contentbox3 {
padding: 50px;
background: #1e75bc;
margin-bottom: 75px;
}

#contentbox4wrapper {
width: 46.25%;
float: right;
}

#contentbox4 {
padding: 50px;
background: #eaeaea;
margin-bottom: 75px;
}
```

And HTML :

```
<div id="homepageContent">
<div id="contentbox1wrapper">
    <div id="contentbox1">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="contentbox2wrapper">
    <div id="contentbox2">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="contentbox3wrapper">
    <div id="contentbox3">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="contentbox4wrapper">
    <div id="contentbox4">

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you'll need to use media queries. So then on say a mobile device you'll need to make the content `display: block;` and `width: 100%;`. And they should fall down nicely. Check out http://arcsec.ca/media-query-builder/

Comment: @MaraisRossouw I've got all the media queries set up to make it work - if you have a look at the website itself (http://wealthartistry.com.au/wa) it functions perfectly fine for the most part as a responsive site....i'm only having problems with positioning the divs at any size bigger than 799px.

Comment: I omitted the media queries in my code example as they were irrelevant to the larger sized divs. The divs all stack when the browser is narrower than 799px. It's when it is larger that the issue occurs.

Comment: So what exactly is the desired outcome? Are you just trying to get it so that there is no gap between the two boxes on the right hand side?

Comment: @BlakeMann yes. Pretty much. But as it is a responsive site, once it reaches a width of 799px I want the divs to stack on top of one another in order of top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right. Currently it stacks in the right order at a smaller bowser size, but there is a gap between the two boxes on the right hand side when the browser is wider than 799px. If I put the divs in two columns though, it will stack in the wrong order. - You can see an image of the desired outcome here: http://wealthartistry.com.au/wa/templates/protostar/images/Web-Layout---Home-Page3.jpg